# Counting a single variable in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, runnable

I've got the following runnable class.

```
public class OnesRun implements Runnable {

    public int ones = 0;

    private int passendNumber;

    public OnesRun(int passendNumber) {
        this.passendNumber = passendNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (passendNumber == 1)
            ones++;
    }

}
```

Every instance of this class should increase the value of `ones` if it encounters a one.

After all threads have been executed I want to read the value of `ones` from outside the class.

1. How can I increment `ones`
   thread-safe ?
2. How can I access
   `ones` from outside this class?
   Through a static variable? Or can I put it into the application
   context?

---

**Edit:**

I hope the following pseudo code makes my intentions more clear.

```
OnesRun.ones = getCurrentValueOnes();

while ( (number = readNumbersFromFile) != null) {
   threadPool.execute(new OnesRun(number));
}

print("Overall values of ones " + OnesRun.ones);
```

Comment: Note that the pseudo code will most likely do what you want, because the value printed will be somewhere between the 0 and the actual number of ones. The reason for this is that you cannot be sure that all the `OnesRun` instances where executed before you access the count.

Comment: That's right. I would have to wait until all threads have been executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I increment ones thread-safe ?

You can use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

> How can I access ones from outside this class? Through a static variable? Or can I put it into the application context?

You may use a simple getter. Or am I missing something?

#### Update

Based on your update, here is how I would modify your code sample:

```
public class OnesRun implements Runnable {

    private static final AtomicInteger ones = new AtomicInteger();

    private final int passendNumber;

    public OnesRun(int passendNumber) {
        this.passendNumber = passendNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (passendNumber == 1)
            OnesRun.ones.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static void setOnes(int newValue) {
        ones.set(newValue);
    }

    public static int getOnes() {
        return ones.get()
    }
}

...

OnesRun.setOnes(getCurrentValueOnes());

while ( (number = readNumbersFromFile) != null) {
   threadPool.execute(new OnesRun(number));
}

print("Overall values of ones " + OnesRun.getOnes());
```

Apart from what's already been discussed (making `ones` a `private static AtomicInteger` and adding a getter/setter pair), I made both members `final`, which is always advisable if possible, especially in concurrent code.

Note also that `AtomicInteger` is kept as an implementation detail - it is not exposed by the public interface of the class.

Comment: Also, set `ones` to private rather than public to force use of the getter.

Comment: But after all threads have finished, I would have to create a new instance of this class and call the getter, wouldn't I?

Comment: @Bernhard V, if you want to *share* `ones` between every `OnesRun` instance, make it `static`, with a `static` getter.

Comment: I've edited my question. I hope this helps you in understanding me.

Answer (score 0):

Use AtomicInteger (thread-safe) and static property.

```
public class OnesRun implements Runnable {
    private static final AtomicInteger ones = new AtomicInteger();

    private int passendNumber;

    public OnesRun(int passendNumber) {
        this.passendNumber = passendNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (passendNumber == 1) {
            ones.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    public static AtomicInteger getOnes() {
        return ones;
    }
}


OnesRun.getOnes().set(getCurrentValueOnes());

while ( (number = readNumbersFromFile) != null) {
    threadPool.execute(new OnesRun(number));
}

print("Overall values of ones " + OnesRun.getOnes().get());
```